# Change array of object to CSV pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, csv

i have this following Array :

```
var objRow = [
    {
        2011-09-20 : [0, 100, 0],
        customerID : C1101,
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        2011-09-25 : [0, 0, 0],
        customerID : C1101,
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        2011-09-20 : [0, 500, 0],
        customerID : C1102,
        ANI : 5678
    },
    {
        2011-09-22 : [0, 0, 50],
        customerID : C1102,
        ANI : 5678
    }
]
```

I want to create CSV Data from array above. But, i have problem to change that array to this CSV pattern :

```
1234, C1101, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0
5678, C1102, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 50
```

I try to group the `customerID` using *reduce*, and because the first index in every object is date. I have some array of dates :

```
var dateArr = ["2011-09-20", "2011-09-22", "2011-09-25"];
```

And this is my code :

```
var result = objRow.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, arr) {
    var num = curr["customerID"];

    if (!prev[num]) {
        prev[num] = [];
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < dateArr.length; j++) {
        prev[num].push(curr[dateArr[j]]);
    }

    return prev;
}, {});
```

**Update Question**
For number combination in `date` index. I use this rules :

```
[0, 100, 0] // from first Object
[0, 0, 0] // from second Object


fistObject_firstIndex, secondObject_firstIndex, firstObject_secondIndex, secondObject_secondIndex, firstObject_thirdIndex, secondObject_thirdIndex
0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0
```

Up, Down, Up, Down, Up, Down...

How to create CSV Pattern above?
Thank you...

Comment: I think csv does not supports arrays

Comment: Why does `[0, 100, 0]` become `0, 0, 100` in the CSV? What's the logic?

Comment: @bto.rdz  yes i know, therefore i want to convert array above to comma separated.

Comment: @Ja͢ck the all indexes combined. index-0_object0 , index-0_object1, index-1_object0, index-1_object1 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you the result you want:

```js
var objRow = [{
  date: 2011-09-20,
  nums: [0, 100, 0],
  customerID: "C1101",
  ANI: 1234
}, {
  date: 2011-09-25,
  nums: [0, 0, 0],
  customerID: "C1101",
  ANI: 1234
}, {
  date: 2011-09-20,
  nums: [0, 500, 0],
  customerID: "C1102",
  ANI: 5678
}, {
  date: 2011-09-22,
  nums: [0, 0, 50],
  customerID: "C1102",
  ANI: 5678
}];


//CREATE CSV-FORMATTED STRINGS
var csvLine = "";
var numsArray = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<objRow.length; i++) {
  //check if this is the first element with a new 'ANI' (which means a new CSV line starts)
  if (objRow[i-1]==(undefined||null) || objRow[i].ANI!=objRow[i-1].ANI) {
    //if so, start a new string
    csvLine = objRow[i].ANI +", "+ objRow[i].customerID +", "; //add the 'ANI' and 'customerID'
    numsArray.length = 0; //clear array
    numsArray.push(objRow[i].nums); //store the 'nums' in a separate array
  } else {
    //if not, add to the existing string
    numsArray.push(objRow[i].nums); //store the 'nums' in a separate array
  }

  //check if this is the last element with the same 'ANI' (which means this CSV line is complete)
  if (objRow[i+1]==(undefined||null) || objRow[i].ANI!=objRow[i+1].ANI) {
    //add the 'nums' of every object in intertwining order (every 1st, every 2nd, etc.)
    for (var k=0; k<numsArray[0].length; k++) {
      for (var j=0; j<numsArray.length; j++) {
        csvLine += numsArray[j][k].toString() +", ";
      }
    }
    //remove the last comma
    if (csvLine.substring(csvLine.length-2) == ", ") {
      csvLine = csvLine.substring(0,csvLine.length-2);
    }
    //output the CSV line
    document.getElementById("csv").innerHTML += csvLine + "<br />";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="csv"></div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gyp3ce6/16/**)

I had to change your array a little bit, because for this to work, the array keys need to all be the same.
Also, I had to change the ID's to strings, otherwise they couldn't be defined.

Instead of writing it to the `<div>` at the end you can of course add the line to another variable of write it to file or whatever.

If the comments in the code aren't clear enough, just leave a comment and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I already update my question, for `nums` rules.

Comment: @fanjavaid - I updated my answer, the nums are now intertwined like in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var objRow = [
    {
        "2011-09-20" : [0, 100, 0],
        customerID : "C1101",
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        "2011-09-25" : [0, 0, 0],
        customerID : "C1101",
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        "2011-09-20" : [0, 500, 0],
        customerID : "C1102",
        ANI : 5678
    },
    {
        "2011-09-22" : [0, 0, 50],
        customerID : "C1102",
        ANI : 5678
    }
];

var arr = [],
    res = [],
    csv = $.map(objRow, function (v, k) {  
        // items         
        arr.push(v.ANI, v.customerID, v[Object.keys(v)[0]]);
        // arrays
        var a = $.grep(arr, function (val, index) {
            return $.isArray(val)
        });
        // strings
        var s = arr.filter(function (i) {
            return typeof i === "string"
        });
        // sort items
        res.push([arr.filter(Number)[0]
                 , s[0]
                 , a.splice(0, 2).join(",")
                 , arr.filter(Number).slice(-1)[0]
                 , s.slice(-1)[0]
                 , a.join(",")]);
        return res
    }).slice(-1)[0];
    // format text , html
    csv = (csv.slice(0, 3) + "<br>" + csv.slice(-3))
          .replace(/,/g, ", ");
    $("body").append(csv)
```

```js
var objRow = [
    {
        "2011-09-20" : [0, 100, 0],
        customerID : "C1101",
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        "2011-09-25" : [0, 0, 0],
        customerID : "C1101",
        ANI : 1234
    },
    {
        "2011-09-20" : [0, 500, 0],
        customerID : "C1102",
        ANI : 5678
    },
    {
        "2011-09-22" : [0, 0, 50],
        customerID : "C1102",
        ANI : 5678
    }
];

var arr = [],
    res = [],
    csv = $.map(objRow, function (v, k) {
        arr.push(v.ANI, v.customerID, v[Object.keys(v)[0]]);
        // arrays
        var a = $.grep(arr, function (val, index) {
            return $.isArray(val)
        });
        // strings
        var s = arr.filter(function (i) {
            return typeof i === "string"
        });

        res.push([arr.filter(Number)[0], s[0], a.splice(0, 2).join(","), arr.filter(Number).slice(-1)[0], s.slice(-1)[0], a.join(",")]);
        return res
    }).slice(-1)[0]; 

csv = (csv.slice(0, 3) + "<br>" + csv.slice(-3))
      .replace(/,/g, ", ");
$("body").append(csv)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```